# Constructor not found on IdentityModel.Client.TokenClient

Tags: deployment, openid, claims-based-identity

I feel this can fall into the bucket of missing/incorrect deployed dlls but as far as I can see on the server this is the only assembly on it and its the same version that works in my local machine.
I was using IdentityModel version 3.7, specifically this constructor,
 and it builds and even runs locally just fine. I deploy it to my QA Server and bam missing method exception. I even upgraded it to 3.9 and deployed just to see if that would work, no change. Unfortunately this assembly doesn't have a public key token, although I searched all drives for another version of IdentityModel.dll and didn't find any. Nothing in the GAC, restart didn't work, I'm out of ideas.

> Method not found: 'Void IdentityModel.Client.TokenClient..ctor(System.String, System.String, System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler, IdentityModel.Client.AuthenticationStyle)'

EDIT I added some logging code

```
    Assembly assem = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(TokenClient));
    FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assem.Location);
    string version = fvi.FileVersion;
    _logger.Error(String.Format("{0} : {1}", assem.FullName, version));
```

and they both print off the same version on both my local box and the broken QA Environment.

Edit 2
I added logging code to log all constructors and methods and on both boxes they print off the same. I can even see my constructor logged off right before the missing method exception.

Answer (score 3):

Holy cow what a trip.

So here is what the issue was, the problem assembly wasnt actually the one containing the class that threw the missing method but rather one of parameters. The System.Net.Http assembly was actually different between my local machine and QA. So really it was a missing method, there was no constructor expecting a different version of that HttpMessageHandler type. by including this in the web.config things are working for me again. The scary part is that it is actually a default parameter so you would not even notice this parameter sometimes

`<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>`

Comment: I had the same issue with RequestPasswordTokenAsync extension method, your answer solved my problem too.